# PHP DomDocument query in results

Tags: php, html, domdocument, domxpath

Yesterday I discovered the php DomDocument and I realized that could help me a lot (way faster - I was using php and regex) to get values from html.

I'm stuck and I can't find a solution (probably my way of thinking) - searched for over 16 hours now and still no solution.

```
$res = '
<html>
<div class="product bla bla">
<div class="size">xxl</div>
<div class="color yy">red</div>
</div>

<div class="product bla">
<div class="size xxs">xxs</div>
<div class="line line2">new</div>
</div>

<div class="product asd">
<div class="color xx">blue</div>
</div>
</html>
';

$dom = new DomDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($res); // utf8_decode
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; // ?
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath ->query("//*[contains(@class, 'product')]");

echo "Found {$nodes->length} matching places" . PHP_EOL;

foreach($nodes  as $node) {
    $name = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'color')]", $node);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $name[0]->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
Found 3 matching places
red
red
red
```

Expected result would be:

```
Found 3 matching places
red
Null / empty or so...
blue
```

My question would be how do I search in  search result  (preserving the index  ex. [0] -  red, [1] - null, 2 - [blue] )

Also if you know a good place to learn about DomDocument let me know

Thank you for your help or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your last lines as:

```
foreach($nodes  as $node){
     // do not use `//` as it means "from the root of the document", 
     // and not from the root of the node you provided
     $name = $xpath->query("*[contains(@class, 'color')]", $node);
     // check if name[0] node exists
     echo null === $name[0] ? 'NULL' : $name[0]->nodeValue;
     echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Fiddle is [here](https://3v4l.org/IQFqd).

Comment: thank you! that's what l was looking for...    also for anybody  looking to learn the XPath Syntax:  [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)